# Java API OpenWeatherMap

Tags: java, openweathermap

I have started learning Java a while back and looking at doing my first advanced (for me) project. I am wanting to create a program that uses the OpenWeatherMap API to show the weather for a particular city.

1. User inputs name of city
2. City stored as variable
3. Call API using city variable
4. Store results in two varibles (City & temp)
5. Display results using System.out.Println(City, Temp)

I have done some reading before starting and I am seeing people saying that storing api results in variables is bad practice? Just checking I am going down the right route before starting?

Below is an example of the API result

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with storing your HTTP results in variables. Usually, one would use a library such as GSON that does the JSON parsing.

Comment: "I am seeing people saying that storing api results in variables is bad practice" which people, where are they saying it?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why storing data in variables is bad practice. The alternative is to chain methods. e.g. instead of this:

```
String cityResult = callApi(city);
JSON jsonCityResult = JSON.parse(cityResult);
print(jsonCityResult.temp);
```

it would be:

```
print(JSON.parse(callApi(city)).temp);
```

which is difficult to read, difficult to maintain and difficult to work out what went wrong. Was it the api call or the `JSON` parse?

As long as the code is 'self documenting', i.e. `cityResult` instead of `cr` I think that is perfectable acceptable programming.